# how to get file creationDate of all files from folder and show in TextView that in gridview android holder.creationdate.settext() something like that?

Tags: android

I am trying this but it gives me the last modified date of the directory, not the file saved in the directory. Early response will be appreciated.

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/Media");


Date lastModified = new Date(dir.lastModified());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModified);


holder.textDate.setText(formattedDateString);
```

Comment: You use the directory. Use the file(s)!

Comment: can you please share any code form where I can get all files from the directory and their saved date?

Comment: Those are two questions. Please first show code to get that date from one file. Put the code in an extra block in your post.

Comment: i dont know how to get the date form one file

Comment: Its the same as from one directory.

Comment: I am stuck brother kindly help me out

Comment: Make a File instance for your file. (Now you make a File instance for your directory).

Comment: Thank you it works just get the path of file from the folder

Answer (score 0):

just change my code to
and the path is the path of my files

```
File dir = new File("");

dir= new File(path);
Date lastModified = new Date(dir.lastModified());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModified);


holder.textDate.setText(formattedDateString);
```